# Proving the equivalent condition for primality

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $p\in\mathbb{N}$, p>1 then p is a prime if and only if for every $a,b\in\mathbb{N}$, p=ab implies a=1 or b=1.

if p=2, then a=1 and b=2,
but if p=6, then a=2 and b=3 or a=1 and b=6.

I understand what it's saying, I just don't even know how to prove this.

P.S. I'm new to proofs.

Comment: @Bernard - nothing in this post claims $6$ is prime. Clearly the $p=6$ case is an example of what happens when $p$ is not prime.

Comment: @Paul Sinclair: You're probably right, and I'll remove my comment, but I found the question ambiguous.

Comment: @Bernard - Once I read through it a couple times, I finally spotted that although it is very close, the condition is not exactly the definition of a prime. Then i understood that it isn't ambiguous, (S)He needs help bridging the small distance between this condition and the actual definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider: the definition of "prime" is that $p$ is prime if (and only if) the only divisors of $p$ are $1$ and itself. When the divisor is 1 you have the condition above obviously. If the divisor is $p$, then ask yourself, what has to be multiplied by $p$ to get $p$. The other direction works the same way.